# Tableau create a table matrix?

Tags: matrix, tableau-api

I have a CSV file that looks like this. It is in matrix form where cell A1 is empty. I want to visualize this in Tableau like [this](http://public.tableau.com/views/CorrelationMatrixTableauExample/CorrelationMatrix?:embed=y&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no#1)

```
   a1,a2,a3
a1,1,0.2,0.3
a2,0.3,1,0.5
a3,0.6,0.7,1
```

How can I build this in tableau to show a matrix?

I tried putting `measure name` in both the row and column field and `measure values` in the `marks` text box but i ended up with diagonal values which isn't what i want.

Answer (score 0):

First structure your data in the form of a table.

A well structured CSV file for Tableau (and most tools) has a single header row that labels each column (so skipping the first cell in the header row is a problem). Then each data row that follows contains only values in each field separated by columns (so there should be no leading row labels)

Order is not significant in a relational table. The rows in a table form a set, not a matrix.

So your CSV should look something closer to

```
field_name_1,field_name_2,field_name_3
1,0.2,0.3
0.3,1,0.5
0.6,0.7,1
```

Normally, the prime use of Tableau is display an aggregated summary of the data, not to display each individual data row. So you can put measure_names on columns and measure_values on the text or label shelf to get a summary of each measure (by default a sum)

If all you want to do is to view the underlying data rows in a table for diagnostics, the easiest way is to use the view data button or menu command.

If you want to build a visualization that displays all the data (without summarizing it) in a table, you have two ways to go. The simplest is if you have a unique primary key in your data, you can place it on the row shelf to get a row in your viz for each row in your data.

If your data rows do not have a primary key, you can turn off aggregate measures from the Analysis menu, but then you'll see multiple values in each table cell. Then to get a row in your viz for each row in your data, put the calculation index() on the rows shelf and change it to discrete.